# Trouble displaying referral link in Laravel customer dashboard

Tags: php, laravel, referrals

I am attempting to integrate a referral system into my existing Laravel v9 application (an event and ticketing system). I found a [package](https://github.com/jijunair/laravel-referral) and tutorial on a GitHub repository. Despite following all the instructions, I continually need help with errors.

This code is supposed to display the referral link in the customer dashboard, but I get a 500 server error each time.

```
$referralLink = $user->getReferralLink();
```

**User model**

```
namespace App\Models;

use App\Models\Curriculum\CourseEnrolment;
use App\Models\Curriculum\CourseReview;
use App\Models\Curriculum\QuizScore;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Jijunair\LaravelReferral\Traits\Referrable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
  use HasFactory, Notifiable;
  use Referrable;

  /**
   * The attributes that are mass assignable.
   *
   * @var array
   */
  protected $fillable = [
    'first_name',
    'last_name',
    'image',
    'username',
    'email',
    'email_verified_at',
    'password',
    'contact_number',
    'address',
    'city',
    'state',
    'country',
    'status',
    'verification_token',
    'edit_profile_status'
  ];

  /**
   * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
   *
   * @var array
   */
  protected $hidden = [
    'password',
    'remember_token',
  ];

  /**
   * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
   *
   * @var array
   */
  protected $casts = [
    'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
  ];

  public function courseEnrol()
  {
    return $this->hasMany(CourseEnrolment::class, 'user_id', 'id');
  }

  public function review()
  {
    return $this->hasMany(CourseReview::class, 'user_id', 'id');
  }

  public function quizScore()
  {
    return $this->hasMany(QuizScore::class, 'user_id', 'id');
  }
}
```

**Customer model**

```
namespace App\Models;

use App\Models\Event\Booking;
use App\Models\Event\Wishlist;
use App\Models\ShopManagement\OrderItem;
use App\Models\ShopManagement\ProductOrder;
use App\Models\ShopManagement\ProductReview;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;

class Customer extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract
{
  use HasFactory, Authenticatable;
  protected $fillable = [
    'provider',
    'provider_id',
    'fname',
    'lname',
    'username',
    'email',
    'photo',
    'phone',
    'address',
    'country',
    'state',
    'city',
    'zip_code',
    'password',
    'gender',
    'status',
    'email_verified_at',
    'verification_token'
  ];

  protected $hidden = [
    'password',
    'remember_token',
    'two_factor_recovery_codes',
    'two_factor_secret',
  ];

  protected $casts = [
    'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
  ];
  /**
   * The accessors to append to the model's array form.
   *
   * @var array
   */
  protected $appends = [
    'profile_photo_url',
  ];

  //bookings
  public function bookings()
  {
    return $this->hasMany(Booking::class);
  }
  //order_items
  public function order_items()
  {
    return $this->hasMany(OrderItem::class, 'user_id', 'id');
  }
  //product_orders
  public function product_orders()
  {
    return $this->hasMany(ProductOrder::class, 'user_id', 'id');
  }
  //product_reviews
  public function product_reviews()
  {
    return $this->hasMany(ProductReview::class, 'user_id', 'id');
  }
  //support_tickets
  public function support_tickets()
  {
    return $this->hasMany(SupportTicket::class, 'user_id', 'id');
  }
  //wishlists
  public function wishlists()
  {
    return $this->hasMany(Wishlist::class, 'customer_id', 'id');
  }
}
```

**this is the view i am trying to display the referral link**

```
<!--====== Start Dashboard Section ======-->
    <section class="user-dashbord">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                @includeIf('frontend.customer.partials.sidebar')
                <div class="col-lg-9">
                    <div class="row mb-5">
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <div class="user-profile-details">
                                <div class="account-info">
                                    <div class="title">
                                        <h4>{{ __('Account Information') }}</h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="main-info">
                                        <h5>{{ __('User') }}</h5>
                                        <ul class="list">
                                            @if (Auth::guard('customer')->user()->email != null)
                                                <li><b>{{ __('Email') . ' : ' }}</b></li>
                                            @endif
                                            @if (Auth::guard('customer')->user()->username != null)
                                                <li><b>{{ __('Username') . ' : ' }}</b></li>
                                            @endif
                                            @if (Auth::guard('customer')->user()->phone != null)
                                                <li><b>{{ __('Phone') . ' : ' }}</b></li>
                                            @endif
                                            @if (Auth::guard('customer')->user()->address != null)
                                                <li><b>{{ __('Address') . ' : ' }}</b></li>
                                            @endif
                                            @if (Auth::guard('customer')->user()->country != null)
                                                <li><b>{{ __('Country') . ' : ' }}</b></li>
                                            @endif
                                            @if (Auth::guard('customer')->user()->city != null)
                                                <li><b>{{ __('City') . ' : ' }}</b></li>
                                            @endif
                                            @if (Auth::guard('customer')->user()->state != null)
                                                <li><b>{{ __('State') . ' : ' }}</b></li>
                                            @endif
                                            @if (Auth::guard('customer')->user()->zip_code != null)
                                                <li><b>{{ __('Zip-code') . ' : ' }} </b></li>
                                            @endif
                                            @if(Auth::guard('customer')->check())
                                        
                                            @if(Auth::guard('customer')->check())
                                        
                                            @if(Auth::guard('customer')->check())
                                            @php
                                                $user = Auth::guard('customer')->user();
                                                $referralLink = $user->getReferralLink();
                                            @endphp

                                            @if ($user->hasReferralAccount())
                                                <p>Your referral link: {{ $referralLink }}</p>
                                            @else
                                                <p>You do not have a referral account.</p>
                                            @endif
                                        @endif

                                           
                                        @endif

                                        
                                         
                                    @endif

                                        </ul>
```

**customer controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\FrontEnd;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\Admin;
use App\Models\BasicSettings\Basic;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Organizer;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Rules\MatchEmailRule;
use App\Models\BasicSettings\MailTemplate;
use App\Models\Customer;
use App\Models\Event\Booking;
use App\Models\Event\Wishlist;
use App\Models\Language;
use App\Rules\MatchOldPasswordRule;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
use Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite;
use Jijunair\LaravelReferral\Models\Referral;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie;

class CustomerController extends Controller
{
  private $admin_user_name;
  public function __construct()
  {
    $admin = Admin::select('username')->first();
    $this->admin_user_name = $admin->username;
  }

  //index
  public function index()
  {
    $bookings = Booking::where('customer_id', Auth::guard('customer')->user()->id)->OrderBy('id', 'desc')->limit(10)->get();
    $language = Language::query()->where('is_default', '=', 1)->first();
    return view('frontend.customer.dashboard.index', compact('bookings'));
    $referralCode = Cookie::get(config('referral.cookie_name'));
    $referrer = Referral::userByReferralCode($referralCode);
    $user->hasReferralAccount();
    $user->createReferralAccount($referrer->id);
    $referrals = $user->referrals;
  }
  //signup
  public function signup()
  {
    return view('frontend.customer.signup');
  }
  //create
  public function create(Request $request)
  {

    $rules = [
      'fname' => 'required',
      'lname' => 'required',
      'email' => 'required|email|unique:customers',
      'username' => [
        'required',
        'alpha_dash',
        "not_in:$this->admin_user_name",
        Rule::unique('customers', 'username')
      ],
      'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
    ];

    $info = Basic::select('google_recaptcha_status')->first();
    if ($info->google_recaptcha_status == 1) {
      $rules['g-recaptcha-response'] = 'required|captcha';
    }

    $messages = [];

    if ($info->google_recaptcha_status == 1) {
      $messages['g-recaptcha-response.required'] = 'Please verify that you are not a robot.';
      $messages['g-recaptcha-response.captcha'] = 'Captcha error! try again later or contact site admin.';
    }

    $request->validate($rules, $messages);

    $in = $request->all();
    $in['password'] = Hash::make($request->password);
    // first, generate a random string
    $randStr = Str::random(20);

    // second, generate a token
    $token = md5($randStr . $request->fname . $request->email);

    $in['verification_token'] = $token;

    // send a mail to user for verify his/her email address
    $this->sendVerificationMail($request, $token);
    Customer::create($in);

    return redirect()->route('customer.login');
  }
  public function sendVerificationMail(Request $request, $token)
  {
    // first get the mail template information from db
    $mailTemplate = MailTemplate::where('mail_type', 'verify_email')->first();
    $mailSubject = $mailTemplate->mail_subject;
    $mailBody = $mailTemplate->mail_body;

    // second get the website title & mail's smtp information from db
    $info = DB::table('basic_settings')
      ->select('website_title', 'smtp_status', 'smtp_host', 'smtp_port', 'encryption', 'smtp_username', 'smtp_password', 'from_mail', 'from_name')
      ->first();

    $link = '<a href=' . url("customer/signup-verify/" . $token) . '>Click Here</a>';

    $mailBody = str_replace('{username}', $request->fname . ' ' . $request->lname, $mailBody);
    $mailBody = str_replace('{verification_link}', $link, $mailBody);
    $mailBody = str_replace('{website_title}', $info->website_title, $mailBody);

    // initialize a new mail
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
    $mail->Encoding = 'base64';

    // if smtp status == 1, then set some value for PHPMailer
    if ($info->smtp_status == 1) {
      $mail->isSMTP();
      $mail->Host       = $info->smtp_host;
      $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
      $mail->Username   = $info->smtp_username;
      $mail->Password   = $info->smtp_password;

      if ($info->encryption == 'TLS') {
        $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;
      }

      $mail->Port       = $info->smtp_port;
    }

    // finally add other informations and send the mail
    try {
      $mail->setFrom($info->from_mail, $info->from_name);
      $mail->addAddress($request->email);

      $mail->isHTML(true);
      $mail->Subject = $mailSubject;
      $mail->Body = $mailBody;

      $mail->send();

      Session::flash('success', 'A verification mail has been sent to your email address.');
    } catch (Exception $e) {
      Session::flash('error', 'Mail could not be sent!');
    }

    return;
  }
  public function signupVerify(Request $request, $token)
  {
    try {
      $customer = Customer::where('verification_token', $token)->firstOrFail();

      // after verify customer email, put "null" in the "verification token"
      $customer->update([
        'email_verified_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        'status' => 1,
        'verification_token' => null
      ]);

      Session::flash('success', 'Your email has verified.');
      // after email verification, authenticate this customer
      Auth::guard('customer')->login($customer);

      return redirect()->route('customer.dashboard');
    } catch (ModelNotFoundException $e) {
      Session::flash('error', 'Could not verify your email!');

      return redirect()->route('customer.signup');
    }
  }

  //login
  public function login(Request $request)
  {
    if ($request->input('redirectPath') == 'event_details') {
      $url = url()->previous();
    }
    if ($request->input('redirectPath') == 'checkout') {
      $url = url()->previous();
    }

    // when user have to redirect to course details page after login.
    if (isset($url)) {
      $request->session()->put('redirectTo', $url);
    }

    return view('frontend.customer.login');
  }


  //authenticate
  public function authentication(Request $request)
  {
    // at first, get the url from session which will be redirect after login
    if ($request->session()->has('redirectTo')) {
      $redirectURL = $request->session()->get('redirectTo');
    } else {
      $redirectURL = null;
    }
    $rules = [
      'username' => 'required',
      'password' => 'required'
    ];

    $info = Basic::select('google_recaptcha_status')->first();
    if ($info->google_recaptcha_status == 1) {
      $rules['g-recaptcha-response'] = 'required|captcha';
    }

    $messages = [];

    if ($info->google_recaptcha_status == 1) {
      $messages['g-recaptcha-response.required'] = 'Please verify that you are not a robot.';
      $messages['g-recaptcha-response.captcha'] = 'Captcha error! try again later or contact site admin.';
    }

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules, $messages);


    if ($validator->fails()) {
      return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator->errors());
    }

    if (
      Auth::guard('customer')->attempt([
        'username' => $request->username,
        'password' => $request->password
      ])
    ) {
      $authAdmin = Auth::guard('customer')->user();

      // check whether the admin's account is active or not
      if ($authAdmin->status == 0) {
        Session::flash('alert', 'Sorry, your account has been deactivated!');
        // logout auth admin as condition not satisfied
        Auth::guard('customer')->logout();

        return redirect()->back();
      } elseif ($authAdmin->email_verified_at == null) {
        Session::flash('alert', 'Sorry, Please verify your email address !');
        // logout auth admin as condition not satisfied
        Auth::guard('customer')->logout();

        return redirect()->back();
      } else {
        // otherwise, redirect auth user to next url
        if ($redirectURL == null) {
          return redirect()->route('customer.dashboard');
        } else {
          // before, redirect to next url forget the session value
          $request->session()->forget('redirectTo');

          return redirect($redirectURL);
        }
      }
    } else {
      return redirect()->back()->with('alert', 'Oops, Username or password does not match!');
    }
  }
  //forget_passord
  public function forget_passord()
  {
    return view('frontend.customer.forget-password');
  }
  //forget_mail
  public function forget_mail(Request $request)
  {
    $rules = [
      'email' => [
        'required',
        'email:rfc,dns',
        new MatchEmailRule('organizer')
      ]
    ];

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
      return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
    }

    $user = Organizer::where('email', $request->email)->first();

    // first, get the mail template information from db
    $mailTemplate = MailTemplate::where('mail_type', 'reset_password')->first();
    $mailSubject = $mailTemplate->mail_subject;
    $mailBody = $mailTemplate->mail_body;

    // second, send a password reset link to user via email
    $info = DB::table('basic_settings')
      ->select('website_title', 'smtp_status', 'smtp_host', 'smtp_port', 'encryption', 'smtp_username', 'smtp_password', 'from_mail', 'from_name')
      ->first();

    $name = $user->name;
    $token =  Str::random(32);
    DB::table('password_resets')->insert([
      'email' => $user->email,
      'token' => $token,
    ]);

    $link = '<a href=' . url("customer/reset-password?token=" . $token) . '>Click Here</a>';

    $mailBody = str_replace('{customer_name}', $name, $mailBody);
    $mailBody = str_replace('{password_reset_link}', $link, $mailBody);
    $mailBody = str_replace('{website_title}', $info->website_title, $mailBody);

    // initialize a new mail
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
    $mail->Encoding = 'base64';

    // if smtp status == 1, then set some value for PHPMailer
    if ($info->smtp_status == 1) {
      $mail->isSMTP();
      $mail->Host       = $info->smtp_host;
      $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
      $mail->Username   = $info->smtp_username;
      $mail->Password   = $info->smtp_password;

      if ($info->encryption == 'TLS') {
        $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;
      }

      $mail->Port       = $info->smtp_port;
    }

    // finally add other informations and send the mail
    try {
      $mail->setFrom($info->from_mail, $info->from_name);
      $mail->addAddress($request->email);

      $mail->isHTML(true);
      $mail->Subject = $mailSubject;
      $mail->Body = $mailBody;

      $mail->send();

      Session::flash('success', 'A mail has been sent to your email address.');
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
      Session::flash('error', 'Mail could not be sent!');
    }

    // store user email in session to use it later
    $request->session()->put('userEmail', $user->email);

    return redirect()->back();
  }
  //reset_password
  public function reset_password()
  {
    return view('frontend.customer.reset-password');
  }
  //update_password
  public function update_password(Request $request)
  {
    $request->validate([
      'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
      'token' => 'required',
    ]);
    $reset = DB::table('password_resets')->where('token', $request->token)->first();
    $email = $reset->email;
    $customer = Customer::where('email',  $email)->first();
    $customer->password = Hash::make($request->password);
    $customer->save();
    Session::flash('success', 'Your password has been reset.');

    return redirect()->route('customer.login');
  }
  public function logout(Request $request)
  {
    Auth::guard('customer')->logout();

    return redirect()->route('customer.login');
  }
  //change_password
  public function change_password()
  {
    return view('frontend.customer.dashboard.change-password');
  }
  //update_password
  public function updated_password(Request $request)
  {
    $rules = [
      'current_password' => [
        'required',
        new MatchOldPasswordRule('customer')

      ],
      'new_password' => 'required|confirmed',
      'new_password_confirmation' => 'required'
    ];

    $messages = [
      'new_password.confirmed' => 'Password confirmation does not match.',
      'new_password_confirmation.required' => 'The confirm new password field is required.'
    ];

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules, $messages);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
      return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
    }

    $customer = Auth::guard('customer')->user();

    $customer->update([
      'password' => Hash::make($request->new_password)
    ]);

    Session::flash('success', 'Password updated successfully!');

    return back();
  }
  //edit_profile
  public function edit_profile()
  {
    return view('frontend.customer.dashboard.edit-profile');
  }
  //update_profile
  public function update_profile(Request $request)
  {
    $request->validate([
      'fname' => 'required',
      'lname' => 'required',
      'email' => [
        'required',
        'email',
        Rule::unique('customers', 'email')->ignore(Auth::guard('customer')->user()->id)
      ],
      'username' => [
        'required',
        'alpha_dash',
        "not_in:$this->admin_user_name",
        Rule::unique('customers', 'username')->ignore(Auth::guard('customer')->user()->id)
      ],
      'photo' => $request->hasFile('photo') ? 'mimes:jpg,jpeg,png' : ''
    ]);

    $in = $request->all();
    $file = $request->file('photo');
    if ($file) {
      $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
      $directory = public_path('assets/admin/img/customer-profile/');
      $fileName = uniqid() . '.' . $extension;
      @mkdir($directory, 0775, true);
      $file->move($directory, $fileName);
      $in['photo'] = $fileName;
    }
    $id = Auth::guard('customer')->user()->id;
    $update = Customer::find($id)->update($in);
    Session::flash('success', 'Your profile has been successfully updated!');

    return back();
  }
  //wishlist
  public function wishlist()
  {
    $language = $this->getLanguage();
    $customer_id = Auth::guard('customer')->user()->id;
    $wishlist = Wishlist::where('customer_id', $customer_id)
      ->get();
    return view('frontend.customer.dashboard.wishlist', compact('wishlist'));
  }
  //remove_wishlist
  //add_to_wishlist
  public function remove_wishlist($id)
  {
    if (Auth::guard('customer')->check()) {
      $remove = Wishlist::where([['event_id', $id], ['customer_id', Auth::guard('customer')->user()->id]])->first();
      if ($remove) {
        $remove->delete();
        $notification = array('message' => 'Removed from wishlist successfully..!', 'alert-type' => 'info');
      } else {
        $notification = array('message' => 'Something went wrong', 'alert-type' => 'danger');
      }
      return back()->with($notification);
    } else {
      return redirect()->route('customer.login');
    }
  }

  public function facebookRedirect()
  {
    return Socialite::driver('facebook')->redirect();
  }

  public function handleFacebookCallback()
  {
    return $this->authenticationViaProvider('facebook');
  }

  public function googleRedirect()
  {
    return Socialite::driver('google')->redirect();
  }

  public function handleGoogleCallback()
  {
    return $this->authenticationViaProvider('google');
  }

  public function authenticationViaProvider($driver)
  {
    try {

      $user = Socialite::driver($driver)->user();
      $isUser = Customer::where('provider_id', $user->id)->first();

      if ($isUser) {
        Auth::guard('customer')->login($isUser);
        return redirect()->route('customer.dashboard');
      } else {
        //get and insert image
        $avatar = $user->getAvatar();
        $fileContents = file_get_contents($avatar);

        $avatarName = $user->getId() . '.jpg';
        $path = public_path('assets/admin/img/customer-profile/');

        file_put_contents($path . $avatarName, $fileContents);

        $createUser = Customer::create([
          'photo' => $avatarName,
          'fname' => $user->name,
          'email' => $user->email,
          'username' => $user->id,
          'provider' => $driver,
          'provider_id' => $user->id,
          'password' => encrypt('123456'),
          'email_verified_at' => now()
        ]);

        Auth::guard('customer')->login($createUser);
        return redirect()->route('customer.dashboard');
      }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
    }
  }
}
```

**I tryed to use this in the customer dashboard view**

```
@if(Auth::guard('customer')->check())
    @php
        $user = Auth::guard('customer')->user();
        $referralLink = $user->getReferralLink();
    @endphp

    @if ($user->hasReferralAccount())
        <p>Your referral link: <a href="{{ $referralLink }}">{{ $referralLink }}</a></p>
    @else
        <p>You do not have a referral account.</p>
    @endif
@endif
```

I encountered a 500 server error. My goal is to display the referral link in the customer dashboard, enabling other users to register using this link. The referrer should then receive a reward in their dashboard. Additionally, I want the admin to have the ability to oversee and manage the referral system.

**Error Logs**

> [2024-03-29 17:36:37] local.ERROR: Call to undefined method
> App\Models\Customer::getReferralLink()
> {"view":{"view":"C:\xampp\htdocs\host\resources\views\frontend\customer\dashboard\index.blade.php","data":{"websiteInfo":"<pre
> class=sf-dump id=sf-dump-231541494 data-indent-pad="  ">{#303
> +"<span class=sf-dump-public title="Runtime added dynamic property">favicon": "<span class=sf-dump-str title="17
> characters">658d47b989d60.png"
> +"<span class=sf-dump-public title="Runtime added dynamic property">website_title": "<span class=sf-dump-str title="6
> characters">Engage"
> +"<span class=sf-dump-public title="Runtime added dynamic property">logo": "<span class=sf-dump-str title="17
> characters">658d537fdc976.png"
> +"<span class=sf-dump-public title="Runtime added dynamic property">timezone": "<span class=sf-dump-str title="12
> characters">Africa/Lagos"
> +"<span class=sf-dump-public title="Runtime added dynamic property">preloader": "<span class=sf-dump-str title="17
> characters">63cbb14274c51.gif"
> }

Comment: Can you look into the server logs and tell us what the full error message is? Thanks!

Comment: Please enable error logging. Laravel provides excellent tools for this case. Also, are you sure your problem is directly related to [tag:referrals] or [tag:reward-system]? If not, please remove these tags

Comment: Finally, your architecture could be improved. A controller should not contain that much logic (for example: generating random strings, writing the content of a mail and sending it, handling the authentication request,....), use seperate services that could be reused.

Comment: `Call to undefined method App\Models\Customer::getReferralLink()` - anything unclear about that?

Comment: I've been trying to figure out how to solve that problem. I'm a newbie whose trying to learn more.

Comment: The error logging is updated @lajosArpad

Comment: Seems like you are trying to call a referral link on Cusomer model not User where it exists... You did not include that trait in Customer model... Try to add 'use Referrable;' to Customer model.

Also revisit your logic and determine for what actually do you want to have referral links, is it Customers, Users or both

Comment: I wish to have referral links for customer. I have added the traits "use Referrable" to customer model. now i get "Undefined variable $referralLink"

Comment: ```getReferralLink``` is not found in your ```Customer Model``` as @NicoHaase said "anything unclear about that?

Comment: Thank you everyone, I have solved this problem. Now the referral link displays in the customer dashboard but when clicked and registered by another user, it will not count as referred user to the referrer.

Answer (score 0):

`getReferralLink` did not exist because you are missing `use Referrable` in the customer model. Once you added it, you've got past this problem and stumbled into the next one, which complained of

> Undefined variable $referralLink

This happened either because `getReferralLink` returned `null` for the customer, or you used `$referralLink` in a scenario where it was not initialized. You will need to debug this in order to find out what the exact case was.